# how to convert this extension func swift to objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift

how to convert it

```
function calRound() -> String {

        if self > 1000 {

            let number02 = ((self/1000)*10).rounded()/10
            let someD = number02.format(f: ".1")
            return  "\(someD) km."

        }else{
            let someD = self.format(f: ".0")
            return  "\(someD) m."
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming since the code does `self/1000` your function is actually part of an extension to some type of number, along with `rounded` and `format`. Mind you, I'd just use [`MeasurementFormatter`](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-measurementformatter/) which would probably do most of what you seem to be asking

Comment: extension Double {
    func format(f: String) -> String {
        return String(format: "%\(f)f", self)
    }
    
    func calRound() -> String {
        
        if self > 1000 {
            
            let number02 = ((self/1000)*10).rounded()/10
            let someD = number02.format(f: ".1")
            return  "\(someD) km."
            
        }else{
            let someD = self.format(f: ".0")
            return  "\(someD) m."
        }
        
    }
}

Comment: I want to convert to write OBJ-C

Comment: can you please tell which class you have extented? NSNumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent method. Not sure where you should put this, may be somewhere in utility `class`.

```
- (NSString*) formatValue: (double) value {
    NSString* formatted;
    if (value > 1000) {
        double someD = round(((value/1000)*10))/10;
        formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f km.", someD];
    } else {
        formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f km.", value];
    }
    return formatted;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I write nearly same but code you is perfect for me haha

Answer (score 0):

I can convert code function by this code

- (NSString *) calcRound:(double)number{

if (number > 1000 ){

```
    double number02 =  round(((number/1000)*10))/10;


    someD =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f km.", number02];


    return  someD;  //["\(%@) km.", someD ];


}else{

    someD =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f m.", number];

    return  someD;  //["\(%@) m.", someD ];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about an NSNumber extension maybe this would help?

```
@interface NSNumber (roundOf)
- (NSString *)roundOf;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (roundOf)
-(NSString *)roundOf{
    if (self.doubleValue > 1000) {
        double value = round(((self.doubleValue/1000)*10))/10;
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f km.", value];
    } else {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f km.", self.doubleValue];
    }
}
@end
```